# Add label to image NodeJS ImageMagick

Tags: node.js, image, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

Apologies if this has been asked but I am struggling to find the answer.

I am using the Node GM package with ImageMagick. As I am under the impression the `label` only works there.

I want to take an image and add a `label` over the top of it.

I was originally using `drawText()` to acheive this, however I need to take advantage of the auto sizing of the `label` in IM. What I have is:

```
im(path.join(__dirname, '../public/images/imgen/backgrounds/', color + '_' + type + '.png'))
    .gravity('West')
    .fill('#FFFFFF')
    .font(path.join(__dirname, '../public/fonts/Lato/Lato-Bold.ttf'))
    .out('label: ' + text)
    .write(
      path.join(__dirname, '../public/images/imgen/generated/', fileName), function(err) {
        if (!err) {
          // If the write was successful then redirect to the new image
          res.redirect('/images/imgen/generated/' + fileName);
        } else {
          console.error(err);
          res.status(500).end();
        }
    });
```

The above generates two images instead of one. I'm guessing I need to create an empty image and insert the image as a background. Yet I can not work out how to do this.

```
im(1080, 1080)
    .gravity('West')
    .fill('#FFFFFF')
    .font(path.join(__dirname, '../public/fonts/Lato/Lato-Bold.ttf'))
    // Add the image as a background here
    .out('label: ' + text)
    .write(
      path.join(__dirname, '../public/generated/', fileName), function(err) {
        if (!err) {
          // If the write was successful then redirect to the new image
          res.redirect('/images/imgen/generated/' + fileName);
        } else {
          console.error(err);
          res.status(500).end();
        }
    });
```

Where it says Add the image as a background here, I don't know what to do to add an image. I can't find it anywhere in the gm docs to insert an image.

I have tried `.out('texture: ...')` and `.out('background: ...')` but no look. I get the following error from IM `convert: no decode delegate for this image format`TEXTURE' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.`

I'm probably not understanding correctly the out() method. But digging through Github issues and search results hasn't yielded the answer.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a real mental block with all those parentheses in `node.js` but you said any help is welcome, so maybe we can get you sorted out by working a bit towards each other. I'll start at the command-line with **ImageMagick** and then you will maybe understand what is going on behind the scenes and be able to translate that to `node.js`.

The first thing is that ImageMagick operators without a dash before them and with a colon after them generate their own canvas - that means they don't don't need some pre-existing thing to write or draw on. Examples are `canvas:`, `xc:`, `gradient:`, `label:`:

```
convert -size 100x80 canvas:red a.jpg               # "canvas: is same as "xc:"
```

[image]

```
convert -size 100x80 gradient:cyan-magenta a.jpg    # "gradient:" has a colon
```

[image]

```
convert -size 400x60 -undercolor yellow label:"This will be autosized to fit" -trim c.jpg
```

[image]

```
convert -size 400x60 -undercolor yellow label:"... so will this" -trim c.jpg
```

[image]

Hopefully you can see ImageMagick chose a bigger font for the shorter message.

All that is fine, but if you want to use `-annotate` (which you will notice is preceded by a dash and does not have a colon after it), you need to create a canvas first and then annotate it afterwards like this:

```
convert -size 400x120 xc:blue -fill yellow -annotate +40+80  "Annotation" c.jpg
```

[image]

What I am getting to, is that if you create a canvas AND a label (which creates its own canvas, remember), you will effectively have two canvases and get two output images. So, you have two options on how to get around that. You either:

- use a canvas and annotate it, or
- you create a label and background image and then **composite** the label over the canvas.

I just showed you the first option already, so let's look at the second. You can create a label of the correct size and then position it over a background wherever you like and then composite it onto the background as you wish:

```
convert -size 150x40 -undercolor yellow label:"Some funky text" -trim \
  -size 300x200 -gravity center xc:red +swap -composite result.jpg
```

[image]

So, what that does is create a label that is 150x40 and puts the text on it. The second line then creates another canvas in red of 300x200 and puts it behind the text label (using `+swap`) and composites it into the middle. You see, because I composited the label onto the canvas, they have become a single composite image rather than remaining two independent images.

Here is another example where we have an image of the White House and want to create a label and overlay it. First we create the label, all the correct size and colour, then we load the White House image and swap it to the back before compositing the label on top:

```
magick -size 300x200 -background none -fill magenta label:"Some funky label" -trim whitehouse.jpg +swap -gravity southeast -composite result.png
```

[image]

Hopefully you can see how to put all the beloved parentheses around that to make it into `node.js`....

Comment: Wow thanks @mark-setchell. I didn't know that is how it worked. I didn't get that from the documentation and have only ever use IM with a wrapper (mainly Python). Will try get this working with Node now

Comment: Could I please ask which command is to add another image as the background? The commands you have used all look to be missing from my ImageMagick so I may be doing something wrong.

Comment: I have added an example of that at the end.

Comment: Thank you so much. You've made this really easy for me to grasp. I can't believe ImageMagick was the tool to defeated me. LOL.

Comment: I've accepted as I can get it to work. Need to clean up the Node stuff and will add it as a comment.

Comment: You could write up the `node` solution as an answer and accept your own answer - so that all can see how it is done :-) I am not worried about points in the least - it's more important to get folks up and running with solutions.

Comment: I'd be interested in the node solution. Currently trying to solve a similar problem with Node GM and ImageMagick.